# Microsoft graph powershell - Can't add license

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a license to a user using the `Set-MgUserLicense` however I am receiving the error: `Set-MgUserLicense: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'AddLicenses'.`

**The main problem** is that I need help putting the license sku the correct way they want. However I wasn't able to find an example online or from documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/set-mguserlicense?view=graph-powershell-beta

Here is the full code:

```
Set-MgUserLicense -UserId "testuser@testuser.com" -addLicenses [SkuId:reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK] -RemoveLicenses @()
```

Here is the full error:

```
Set-MgUserLicense: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'AddLicenses'. 
Cannot convert value "[SkuId:reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK]" to type "Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAssignedLicense[]". 
Error: "Cannot convert the "[SkuId:reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK]" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAssignedLicense"."
```

I also tried:
`reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK`

`SkuId:reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK`

both give the same type of error.

I got the SKU from using MSOnline on a windows computer.

```
AccountSkuId                            ActiveUnits WarningUnits ConsumedUnits
------------                            ----------- ------------ -------------
reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK         31          0            30           
reseller-account:FLOW_FREE              10000       0            5            
reseller-account:CCIBOTS_PRIVPREV_VIRAL 10000       0            1            
reseller-account:POWER_BI_STANDARD      1000000     0            2            
reseller-account:TEAMS_EXPLORATORY      100         0            2            
reseller-account:MCOMEETADV             1           0            1
```

I would have just used MSOnline to add licenses to a user but that doesn't work with powershell.core which means it doesn't work on linux.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Document mentions using hash tables. So maybe try `-addlicenses @{SkuId = 'reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK'}`

Comment: Dude you totally saved my skin. The `reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK` didn't work but it the formating of that "Hash table thingy" did work. When I first tried it said that `reseller-account:ENTERPRISEPACK` isn't a license. So I went onto a windows computer and pulled the exact skuid using azureAD module and this: `Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select -Property Sku*,ConsumedUnits -ExpandProperty PrepaidUnits` I then used that to get the right Skuid. I will leave an answer about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AdminOfThings for helping me out.

Basically I need a format of a `Hash Table` thingy. I say "thingy" because I don't know what a hash table is as of yet but this worked.

To add a license to a user on linux using the microsoft graph powershell use the following commands (after logging in to Microsoft graph using the `Connect-MgGraph` module)

```
Set-MgUserLicense -UserId "Enteremail@emailinquestion.com" -addlicenses @{SkuId = 'ENTER_A_SKUID_HERE'} -RemoveLicenses @()
```

A big problem is that when I tried to get the `skuid` it would give me the name rather than the actual SkuID. For this I needed to use a windows computer to use the AzureAD module to get the skuid. (NOTE: AzureAD module doesn't NOT work on Linux fully has its not supported by powershell.core)

```
#Install the module
Install-Module -Name AzureAD

#Connect to the module
Connect-AzureAD

#Use this to get your Skuid, and copy/paste that into your Set-MgUserLicense command
Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Select -Property Sku*,ConsumedUnits -ExpandProperty PrepaidUnits
```